# Why layout appears different in devices?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am not sure why the views are different but not stable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/a"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/a"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/c"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/d"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/c"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/c"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/c"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="D"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/d"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/d"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/d"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="E"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/h"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/g"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/g"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/c"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="H"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/i"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/m"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/h"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="I"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/j"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/n"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/i"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="J"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/m"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/g"
    android:layout_below="@+id/g"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="M"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/n"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/m"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/m"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/m"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="N"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/k"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/n"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/f"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="K"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/l"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/n"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/w"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="L"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/o"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/n"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/n"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/n"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="O"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/s"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/m"
    android:layout_below="@+id/m"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/t"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/n"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/o"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="T"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/p"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/o"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="P"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/r"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/l"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="R"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/u"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/z"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/o"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="U"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/v"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/p"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/q"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="V"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/w"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/p"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/f"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="W"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/q"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/k"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/p"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Q"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/x"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/z"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="X"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/z"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/v"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/q"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Z"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/f"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/e"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/e"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/e"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="F"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/y"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/z"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/z"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/z"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Y"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/five"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/five"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/d"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/four"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/four"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/c"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/three"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/three"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/c"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/two"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/two"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/b"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/one"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/one"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/seven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/six"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/six"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/e"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/three"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Chances:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/a"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/f"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/f"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/seven"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seven"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#B40404"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/g"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/h"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="G"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgI"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgD"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/i" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgL"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgI"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgI"
        android:src="@drawable/l" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgD"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgI"
        android:src="@drawable/d" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgD"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgL"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgI"
        android:text=" ___    ___    ___"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tCoins"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgL"
        android:text="                                "
        android:textColor="#B40404"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tCoins"
        android:src="@drawable/coins" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is what I have in XML Layout.]

[image: This is what it looks like in Galaxy S1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your theme:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar); // Example theme;
```

Holo - Theme_Holo_NoTitleBar

You must call it before:

```
setContentView(...);
```

Or add this to your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can remove `NoActionBar`, and `Fullscreen`, to get different things. Also you can add stuff. If you do it with code, there is autocomplete and you can see all themes and options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That still shows the buttons lying on each other exactly as above in Galaxy S1 but in S3 it appears perfectly fine.

Comment: This is because, these two devices have different resolutions, and DPI. You have to make different layouts, for every device, and place them in separate folders. For example: layout-small, layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge, layout-xxlarge, with layout-xxlarge being for the devices with biggest resolution and displays and layout-small, for the smallest resolutions. These are the names of the folders. The layout must keep the same name. The device automatically knows what layout from what folder to use.

Comment: Is there any example related to this online? I am really new into this.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview . Its helpful.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with developing for android! :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses the holo theme. The second devices uses the pre holo theme.

Comment: How can I fix this so that all the devices have the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your custom theme, so you can have a "standard" theme across any Android version. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html